# Concurrent download in Go

Tags: http, go, concurrency

I wrote a program for downloading files in concurrent / parallel (GOMAXPROCS > 1) manner.

This is my 2<sup>nd</sup> (non-toy) program written in Go.  Please point out areas for improvement:

```
package main

import (
        "errors"
        "fmt"
        "github.com/kennygrant/sanitize"
        "github.com/nu7hatch/gouuid"
        "github.com/op/go-logging"
        "io"
        "net/http"
        "net/url"
        "os"
        "path"
        "path/filepath"
        "strconv"
        "strings"
        "time"
)

type TransferMessage struct {
        urlstr         string
        content_length int64
        transferred    int64
        finished       bool
        filename       string
}

const read_chunk = 65536

func MaybeWarn(err error, format string, args ...interface{}) {
        if err != nil {
                format += " (%s)"
                args = append(args, err)
                log.Warning(format, args...)
        }
}

func MaybeExitErr(err error, format string, args ...interface{}) {
        if err != nil {
                format += " (%s)"
                args = append(args, err)
                log.Error(format, args...)
                os.Exit(1)
        }
}

func GetContLen(resp *http.Response) (content_length int64) {
        clen := resp.Header.Get("Content-Length")
        content_length, err := strconv.ParseInt(clen, 10, 64)
        if err != nil {
                content_length = -1
                MaybeWarn(err, "Cannot read content length for url: %s", resp.Request.URL)
        }
        return
}

func GetUrlFilePath(urlstr string) string {
        urlp, err := url.Parse(urlstr)
        fname := sanitize.Name(urlp.Path)
        if err != nil || fname == "" {
                uid, err := uuid.NewV4()
                MaybeExitErr(err, "Cannot generate uid for filename, problem url: %s, error: %s", urlstr, err)
                fname = uid.String()
        }
        cwd, _ := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
        return filepath.Join(cwd, fname)

}

func DownloadFile(urlstr string, c chan TransferMessage, resp *http.Response) {
        content_length := GetContLen(resp)
        fpath := GetUrlFilePath(urlstr)
        fo, err := os.OpenFile(fpath, os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
        MaybeExitErr(err, "Problem opening file: %s", fpath)
        defer fo.Close()
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        t := time.Now()

        for readnum, total := int64(0), int64(0); ; readnum, err = io.CopyN(fo, resp.Body, read_chunk) {
                total += readnum

                msg := TransferMessage{content_length: content_length,
                        urlstr:      urlstr,
                        transferred: total,
                        finished:    false,
                        filename:    fpath}

                switch err {

                case nil:
                        if time.Since(t).Seconds() > float64(0.2) {
                                log.Debug("Sending msg %s", msg)
                                c <- msg
                                t = time.Now()
                        }

                case io.EOF:
                        log.Debug("Finished, sending msg %s", msg)
                        msg.finished = true
                        c <- msg
                        return

                default:
                        MaybeWarn(err, "Problem copying file %s, skipping URL %s", fpath, urlstr)
                        msg.finished = true
                        c <- msg
                        return
                }

        }

}

func UrlRead(urlstr string, c chan TransferMessage) (start_success bool) {
        hclient := new(http.Client)
        req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", urlstr, nil)
        MaybeWarn(err, "Problem making request for URL %s : %s, skipping this URL", urlstr, req)
        resp, err := hclient.Do(req)
        MaybeWarn(err, "Problem executing HTTP request for URL: %s, skipping this URL", urlstr)
        if resp != nil {
                switch resp.StatusCode {

                case 200:
                        go DownloadFile(urlstr, c, resp)
                        return true

                default:
                        MaybeWarn(errors.New(resp.Status), "Response status code: %s, skipping URL: %s", resp.StatusCode, urlstr)
                }
        }
        return false
}

func SetupLog(level string) {
        eff_level := logging.INFO
        if strings.ToUpper(level) == "DEBUG" {
                eff_level = logging.DEBUG
        }
        logging.SetLevel(eff_level, "")
}

func ConsumeAllNonBlocking(c chan TransferMessage) (msg TransferMessage, read bool) {
        for {
                flag := false
                select {
                case msg := <-c:
                        return msg, true
                default:
                        flag = true
                }
                if flag {
                        break
                }
        }
        return TransferMessage{}, false
}

func UpdateDownloadStatus(dchans *map[string]chan TransferMessage, dstatus *map[string]string) {
        for urlstr, c := range *dchans {
                last_msg, read_some := ConsumeAllNonBlocking(c)
                log.Debug("last_msg %s read_some %s", last_msg, read_some)
                if read_some {
                        switch last_msg.content_length {
                        case -1:
                                (*dstatus)[urlstr] = "?"
                        case 0:
                                (*dstatus)[urlstr] = "100%"
                        default:
                                (*dstatus)[urlstr] = fmt.Sprintf("%d%%", last_msg.transferred*100/last_msg.content_length)
                        }
                        if last_msg.finished {
                                (*dstatus)[urlstr] = "100%"
                        }
                }
        }
}

func PrintDownloadStatus(dchans *map[string]chan TransferMessage, dstatus *map[string]string) {
        for urlstr, _ := range *dchans {
                fmt.Printf("%s ", (*dstatus)[urlstr])
        }
        fmt.Println()

}

func CheckAllValues(dstatus map[string]string, val string) bool {
        for _, v := range dstatus {
                if v != val {
                        return false
                }
        }
        return true
}

func WatchDownloads(dchans map[string]chan TransferMessage) {

        dstatus := make(map[string]string)
        for urlstr, _ := range dchans {
                fmt.Printf("%s ", path.Base(GetUrlFilePath(urlstr)))
                dstatus[urlstr] = "0%"
        }
        fmt.Println()

        t1 := time.Now().Second()
        for {
                UpdateDownloadStatus(&dchans, &dstatus)
                if CheckAllValues(dstatus, "100%") {
                        fmt.Println(strings.Repeat("- ", len(dstatus)))
                        PrintDownloadStatus(&dchans, &dstatus)
                        log.Debug("Completed %s", dstatus)
                        break
                }

                t2 := time.Now().Second()
                if t2-t1 == 1 {
                        PrintDownloadStatus(&dchans, &dstatus)
                        t1 = t2
                }
                time.Sleep(time.Duration(100) * time.Millisecond)
        }
}

func DispatchDownloads(urls []string) {

        dchans := make(map[string]chan TransferMessage)

        for _, urlstr := range urls {
                c := make(chan TransferMessage, 10)
                if UrlRead(urlstr, c) {
                        dchans[urlstr] = c
                }
        }
        WatchDownloads(dchans)
}

var log = logging.MustGetLogger("")

func main() {
        SetupLog("info")
        DispatchDownloads(os.Args[1:])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's super fine to use globals (like `log`) in a small one-file program you've written. To make them more visible declare them at the very top of your file right after your types.

The global `read_chunk` doesn't follow Go naming convention. `readChunk` or `readChunkSize` will do it better.

`SetupLog` is used only once in the main function and it does unnecessarily job. Could be replaced with a single function call:

```
logging.SetLevel(logging.INFO, "")
```

I see how you've used `MaybeWarn`, `MaybeExitErr` and understand that *it can be tedious* to write `if err != nil` after most standard library functions. But it is just how it is. I suggest you to get used to it, handle possible errors in the right place and remove `Maybe*` functions.

`ConsumeAllNonBlocking` has several pitfalls:

- `flag` variable is useless. You can use `break` directly in switch body to break the for loop.
- The `for` loop is not used, it can be omited.
- [receive operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) has second parameter you might want to use

The function is used only once so I suggest you to write the select statement directly in place where you need it:

```
select {
case ret, ok := <- c:
default:
    // will block
}
```

There is no a single comment line across all your code. This can be perfectly valid for a simple program like FizzBuzz, but some complex one like concurrent HTTP downloader deserves some explanation. Same stands for user experience: it's wise to provide a usage string and command line arguments like quiet, read links from stdin and so on.

There is several places were the code is not formatted properly. `go fmt` is on the rescue.